# How can I update a list in mailchimp api version 3 using php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailchimp

I have an existing list in mailchimp. I have cron in my helpers for generating a array list of users every 6 hours. Now I want to send the new email id's from this array to the old list so that just the new email ids' information  will be added to it. How can I do this. I have added mcapi.php in my libraries folder. and I am getting an array named user[]. so how should i call the api and listupdate method ? My mailchimp version is 3.0 and I am using codeigniter framework.

Comment: Which library is mcapi.php? E.g. did you download it from here, https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/? Then which link exactly?